# .htaccess mod_rewrite in main directory and subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've a main directory with a .htaccess file that looks like this

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The one in the subdirectory looks identical to this one. What I want the .htaccess files to do is redirect to the index file in each directory.

So if you visit **main/example** you get redirected to the index.php file in the **main directory** but if you visit **main/subdirectory** you get redirected to the index.php file in the **subdirectory**.

I've searched for an answer but haven't found anything that works.

Thankful for any help!

Comment: You could (1) just use `FallbackResource` instead of that rewrite rule block. Else constrain it with (2) another condition to not match any string containing `/` etc., or use a (3) negative assertion for the subdirectory name.

Comment: The `FallbackResource` did work, but not in the subdirectory. I tried a negative assertion for the subdirectory name but I'm not sure I've done it correctly. Is this correct? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/ $1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! But your solution only works when both .htaccess files use your code, is it possible with with one .htaccess? Another problem I got was that it didn't work on my Synology server only in MAMP. When I add this line: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` the mod_rewrite works fine but my login form breaks...

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ /$1/index.php [L]
```

This configuration do the following:

if we have this files

```
/index.php
/foo/index.php
/var/index.php
/var/boo/index.php
```

and you request the follow file

```
/foo/hello
```

you will go to:

```
/foo/index.php
```

and, if you request

```
/var/boo/world
```

you will go to:

```
/var/boo/index.php
```

Comment: So this kind of works, but I only want the redirect to work in one folder and the root. `root/subdirectory/anotherdirectory/` should redirect to the index.php inside subdirectory and `root/example/` should redirect to the root index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple solution like this one, no need to put .htaccess files everywhere

on your main directory you put one .htaccess file, you keep your code

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and you add those two lines

```
  Options All -Indexes
  ErrorDocument 403 http://domain.com/index.php
```

these two lines prevent the user to access the folder, and returns the statut 403 and then you redirect your 403 statut to the adress of your index.php of your main directory